# How to increase/decrease spacing between two sub figures? and how to center the sub-captions?

Tags: spacing, memoir

I have the following LaTeX code in `memoir` class. I am having problem with the spacing between two top plots. Also the sub figure captions (a), (b) and (c) are not centered. 
I am a beginner in LaTeX but I am writing my PhD thesis. So any quick help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}\small
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=14, ymin=-100, ymax=1200, width =8 cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, xtick distance =3, ytick distance =200, xlabel = Nanosilica content (wt\%), ylabel= {Fracture energy, $G_{IC}$ ${(J/m^2)}$},legend style= {font=\tiny, legend pos= north west, legend cell align={left}}]
\addplot[cyan, thick] coordinates
{(0,220) (3,276) (6,302) (9,322) (12,338)};\addlegendentry{model (3 wt\% CSR-epoxy matrix)};
\addplot[only marks = o*,
    cyan, error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit] table [x=a, y=b, y error = c]{F_7.3a.txt};\addlegendentry{Experimental};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}\label{fig:3a}
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=14, ymin=-100, ymax=1200, width = 8cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, xtick distance =3, ytick distance =200, xlabel = Nanosilica content (wt\%), ylabel= {Fracture energy, $G_{IC}$ ${(J/m^2)}$},legend style= {font=\tiny, legend pos= north west, legend cell align={left}}]
\addplot[cyan, thick] coordinates
{(0,430) (3,548) (6,604) (9,646) (12,681)};\addlegendentry{model (6 wt\% CSR-epoxy matrix)};
\addplot[only marks = o*,
    cyan, error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit] table [x=a, y=b, y error = c]{F_7.3b.txt};\addlegendentry{Experimental};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}\label{fig:10b}
\end{minipage} \par\medskip
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=14, ymin=-100, ymax=1200, width = 8cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, xtick distance =3, ytick distance =200, xlabel = Nanosilica content (wt\%), ylabel= {Fracture energy, $G_{IC}$ ${(J/m^2)}$},legend style= {font=\tiny, legend pos= north west, legend cell align={left}}]
\addplot[cyan, thick] coordinates
{(0,430) (3,548) (6,604) (9,646) (12,681)};\addlegendentry{model (6 wt\% CSR-epoxy matrix)};
\addplot[only marks = o*,
    cyan, error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit] table [x=a, y=b, y error = c]{F_7.3b.txt};\addlegendentry{Experimental};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{}\label{fig:10b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Hybrid modified epoxy}\label{fig:10}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to increase the distance between (a) and (b), as the y axis title of figure (b) is very close to figure (a). Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following MWE (important code changes marked with `<=========`):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\usepackage[%
  margin=1in,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext} % <==============================================
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}


\begin{document} 

\blindtext
\begin{figure}\small
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth} % <==================================
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=14, ymin=-100, ymax=1200, width =8 cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, xtick distance =3, ytick distance =200, xlabel = Nanosilica content (wt\%), ylabel= {Fracture energy, $G_{IC}$ ${(J/m^2)}$},legend style= {font=\tiny, legend pos= north west, legend cell align={left}}]
\addplot[cyan, thick] coordinates
{(0,220) (3,276) (6,302) (9,322) (12,338)};\addlegendentry{model (3 wt\% CSR-epoxy matrix)};
\addplot[only marks = o*,
    cyan, error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit] table [x=a, y=b, y error = c]{F_7.3a.txt};\addlegendentry{Experimental};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{test a}\label{fig:3a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfil % <===============================================================
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth} % <==================================
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=14, ymin=-100, ymax=1200, width = 8cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, xtick distance =3, ytick distance =200, xlabel = Nanosilica content (wt\%), ylabel= {Fracture energy, $G_{IC}$ ${(J/m^2)}$},legend style= {font=\tiny, legend pos= north west, legend cell align={left}}]
\addplot[cyan, thick] coordinates
{(0,430) (3,548) (6,604) (9,646) (12,681)};\addlegendentry{model (6 wt\% CSR-epoxy matrix)};
\addplot[only marks = o*,
    cyan, error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit] table [x=a, y=b, y error = c]{F_7.3b.txt};\addlegendentry{Experimental};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{test test test test test test test test test test test test test test b}\label{fig:10b}
\end{minipage} 
\par\bigskip % \medskip <===============================================
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth} % <==================================
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=14, ymin=-100, ymax=1200, width = 8cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, xtick distance =3, ytick distance =200, xlabel = Nanosilica content (wt\%), ylabel= {Fracture energy, $G_{IC}$ ${(J/m^2)}$},legend style= {font=\tiny, legend pos= north west, legend cell align={left}}]
\addplot[cyan, thick] coordinates
{(0,430) (3,548) (6,604) (9,646) (12,681)};\addlegendentry{model (6 wt\% CSR-epoxy matrix)};
\addplot[only marks = o*,
    cyan, error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit] table [x=a, y=b, y error = c]{F_7.3b.txt};\addlegendentry{Experimental};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{test test test test test test test test test test test test c}\label{fig:10b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Hybrid modified epoxy}\label{fig:10}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

To get a bigger space between subfire a and b you need to reduce the width for the two minipages like:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
```

Change `.45` for your needs (Three times! a), b), and c)). Between both minipages use a `\hfil` to get a small space (1-0.45-0.45=0.1\linewidth) between them ...

To get a bigger space between a/b and subfiger c change `\medskip to`bigskip` like:

```
\par\bigskip % \medskip
```

The subfigures are all centered. To show that I added a subcaption to subfigure b and c. Compare the smaller subcaption of subfigure a with them.

The resulting page of the MWE is:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Mensch